# KAFKA consumer and partition

Tags: apache-kafka, clj-kafka

1) Can any any one explain  how KAFKA consumer knows about partition and consume the data from specific partition?.

What is consumer group?

2) I have 3 partitions  and data stored in all partitions,

for example ( msg1, msg2 , msg3 and msg4).
Msg1 -> partition 2, msg2 -> partition 3, msg3  -> partition 1, msg4 -> partition 4.

So how can I get sequential order of messages (msg) from consumer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Broker partitions are registered in Zookeeper so by querying ZK, consumers can find out what the available partitions are. The high-level consumer is doing this automatically for you.

A consumer group is a common identifier for a group of consumer instances which makes it possible to parallelize consumption for one or more topics. The number of consumers consuming a topic in parallel can be less than or equal to the number of partitions for that topic and partitions will be balanced across consumer instances with the same consumer group id.

2. Kafka guarantees ordered consumption within a partition but not across partitions so if this is needed, it has to be handled at consumer side.